# One-To-Many relation in JPA DELETE operation is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The entity model and repository is given below.

**Channel.java**

```
public class Channel extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "channel_name")
    private String channelName;

    @Column(name = "channel_type")
    private Integer channelType;

    @Column(name = "seq_id")
    private Integer seqId;

    @Column(name = "channel_device_key")
    private String channeldeviceKey;
}
```

**UserRoomChannel.java**

```
public class UserRoomChannel extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_house_id")
    private UserHouse userHouse;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Channel> channels;
}
```

**UserRoomChannelReposirtory.java**

```
public interface UserRoomChannelRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRoomChannel, Long> {
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM user_room_channel_channels WHERE channels_id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteUserRoomChannelChannels(Long id);
}
```

I can save the data successfully. When data is saved through this a third table named `user_room_channel_channels` is created.

EX:

```
    user_room_channel_id   channels_id
           1                   1                   
           1                   2
```

But When I tried to delete with `channels_id` it give me the error

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:.....

`The native query what I write it execute from the command line.`

But using `JPA` I can't do that.

Any help or any suggestion for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced
>   by the owning entity instance

is because *before* you delete your channels(and its children), you somehow do the following:

- you load your `UserRoomChannel` along with its `Channel`s children in the collection from the Database.
- somewhere in your code you change the *reference* of the children collection : `myUserRoomChannel.setChannels(newChannelCollections)` or `myUserRoomChannel.channels =new ChannelCollections();`
- and you try to delete the user with your repositorisory.

Hibernate who remembered having set the children collection with reference A  to the User can find the collection anymore, because `User.channels` is now  `User.channels == B` (with B being a new reference to your collection).

**How to fix it:** 
just find the place where you are replacing your children collections and instead of:

- `myUserRoomChannel.setChannels(newChannelCollections)`, or
- `myUserRoomChannel.channels =new ChannelCollections()`,

just do

```
myUserRoomChannel.getChannels().add/delete/clearYourChannels()
```

Comment: Furthermore, initializing the collection wouldn't hurt either : `private List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @HBo yep, that won't for sure !!

Comment: Thanks for your nice explain. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I just have done the below step and it works perfectly.

- **Reomve:**

  - `myUserRoomChannel.setChannels(channels)`
- **Add**

  - `myUserRoomChannel.getChannels().removeAll(channels)` and then
  - `userRoomChannelRepository.save(myUserRoomChannel)`